# NSTimer countdown not functioning correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, nstimer

I am trying to do the difference between time and display the countdown timer to the user in a ui label

declaration of `NSTimer`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSTimer *timer;
```

this is my timer in view did load

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

and this is my updateCountdown method

```
-(void) updateCountdown:(int)secondsLeft {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    secondsLeft--;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    _countDownlabel.text = [self timeFormatted:secondsLeft];///[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds]);
    if ( secondsLeft == 0 ) {
        [_timer invalidate];
      }
    }
```

and my log details are

```
2017-06-30 09:49:34.070 Barebones[845:56963] requestReply cust liqour category: {
date = "30-6-2017";
"end_time" = "11:41";
"market_crash" = true;
"start_time" = "09:41";
}
2017-06-30 09:49:34.070 Barebones[845:56963] true
2017-06-30 09:49:34.070 Barebones[845:56963] 09:41
2017-06-30 09:49:34.070 Barebones[845:56963] 11:41
2017-06-30 09:49:34.070 Barebones[845:56963] 30-6-2017
2017-06-30 09:49:34.073 Barebones[845:56963] 2016-12-25 08:58:00 +0000
2017-06-30 09:49:34.073 Barebones[845:56963] 2016-12-25 12:15:00 +0000
2017-06-30 09:49:34.073 Barebones[845:56963] 197.000000 is the time  difference
2017-06-30 09:49:34.073 Barebones[845:56963] 00:03:17
2017-06-30 09:49:35.075 Barebones[845:56963] 991:05:35
2017-06-30 09:49:36.075 Barebones[845:56963] 991:05:35
2017-06-30 09:49:37.075 Barebones[845:56963] 991:05:35
2017-06-30 09:49:38.075 Barebones[845:56963] 991:05:35
```

and this value goes on executing

Aim:- to countdown till zero and stop the timer actually I ll be hiding the label once the countdown is over

Update:-

```
 int secondsLeft=[self timeFormatted:[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]/60];
```

have initialised this above timer

this is my updated timer:-

```
int secondsLeft=[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]/60;

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:secondsLeft], @"cID", nil];
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown:) userInfo:userInfo repeats: YES];
```

and this is my updated timer method :-

```
- (void)updateCountdown:(NSTimer *)timer{
int hours, minutes, seconds;
NSDictionary *userInfo = [timer userInfo];
int secondsLeft = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"cID"] intValue];
secondsLeft--;

hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
_countDownlabel.text = [self timeFormatted:secondsLeft];///[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds]);
if ( secondsLeft == 0 ) {
    [_timer invalidate];
  }
}
```

Comment: create secondsLeft as a property. NB: please check my answer. I'm currently working on my existing project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. As vadian said, if you use the selector-based timer, the timer handler function takes a single parameter which is a reference to the timer itself. If you want to keep track of the count down, you can have define properties to keep track of that:

   ```
   @interface ViewController ()

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *stopTime;

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       self.formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
       self.formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
       self.formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
       self.formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;

       self.stopTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5 * 60];   // in 5 minutes, for example

       self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:true];

       [self.timer fire];    // don't wait one second before firing the first time; fire now
   }

   - (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
       NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
       if ([now compare:self.stopTime] == NSOrderedDescending) {
           // do whatever you want when timer stops

           [timer invalidate];
           return;
       }

       self.label.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:now toDate:self.stopTime];
   }

   // Note, when the view disappears, invalidate the timer so the timer doesn't
   // keep strong reference to the view controller. Note that in this selector-based
   // pattern, I can't attempt to do this in `dealloc`, because the scheduled timer
   // will keep a strong reference, preventing `dealloc` from getting called. So do 
   // this in `viewDidDisappear`.

   - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
       [self.timer invalidate];
   }

   @end
   ```
2. If only supporting iOS 10 and later, I'd suggest using the completion block timer, as it simplifies the process even further:

   ```
   @interface ViewController ()

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
       formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
       formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
       formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;

       NSDate *stopTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5 * 60];  // in 5 minutes, for example
       typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; // make sure to not reference `self` in block below, but only reference `weakSelf` to avoid timer from maintaining strong reference

       self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
           NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
           if ([now compare:stopTime] == NSOrderedDescending) {
               // do whatever you want when timer stops

               [timer invalidate];
               return;
           }

           weakSelf.label.text = [formatter stringFromDate:now toDate:stopTime];
       }];

       [self.timer fire];    // don't wait one second before firing the first time; fire now
   }

   // Because I was careful to not reference `self` inside the above block, 
   // this block-based timer will NOT keep a strong reference to the view
   // controller. Nonetheless, when the view controller is dismissed, I want
   // to stop the timer, to avoid wasting CPU cycles on a timer that isn't
   // needed anymore.

   - (void)dealloc {
       [self.timer invalidate];
   }

   @end
   ```

   Clearly, if you need to support iOS 9 and earlier, too, then you have to use the aforementioned selector-based solution.
3. I'd suggest not relying on the timer to adjust the time, as you're not assured that the timer will be called with the frequency you want. In both of the above examples, I capture to what time I'm counting down, and just display the amount of time between "now" and that scheduled "stop time".
4. Note, I'm also suggesting that you get out of the business of building the format string yourself. There's a convenient `NSDateComponentsFormatter` which can format this for you. Use it, if you can.
5. You made your timer reference `strong`. You can make it `weak` because a scheduled timer is not deallocated until it's `invalidated`. And once it's `invalidated`, it's convenient to have it be deallocated automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your action method cannot work.

If a parameter is passed it must be a `NSTimer` instance

```
- (void)updateCountdown:(NSTimer *)timer
```

To pass custom parameters use the `userInfo` argument.

Nevertheless a more suitable solution is to use an instance variable or property because the value of `userInfo` must be an object like `NSNumber`

Comment: if I do that then secondsLeft is not declared so it shows error!!

Comment: and check the updated question I have updated the seconds left I want to countdown that value

Comment: and I am getting incompatible conversion error converting int to id when I did as u advised.    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown:) userInfo:secondsLeft repeats: YES];

Comment: How do you set `secondsLeft` in your original code? The value `userInfo` must be an object (NSNumber). It's recommended to pass a dictionary.

Comment: I think that is the problem I am facing so only I am getting garbage values

Comment: Use an instance variable. It's more convenient.

Comment: hello now I have sent the values correctly but the timer decrements only one time and prints it again n again

Answer (score 1):

Create property

```
@property (nonatomic) int secondsLeft;
```

in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.secondsLeft = 5 * 60; // 5 minutes
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Selector:

```
-(void)updateCountdown{
    int secondsLeft = self.secondsLeft;
    if (secondsLeft >= 0) {
        int minutes, seconds;
        int hours;
        self.secondsLeft--;

        hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
        _countDownlabel.text = [self timeFormatted:secondsLeft];
    }
    if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"TIME ENDS");
        if ([self.timer isValid]) {
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by 60 in `secondsLeft = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]/60`? The “time interval” is the number of seconds, so dividing that by 60 yields the number of minutes between those two dare objects.

Comment: its was just copied from Questioner.